# CSS overflow box height 100%

Tags: css

How can I make this 'scrollbox' fit between the content and the header:
http://jsfiddle.net/LDXhf/5/

(bonus points if it works on IE6)

CSS:

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#header {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {
    position : absolute;
    bottom : 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

#content {
    background-color: white;
}

#scrollbox {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">
       HEADER
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        CONTENT
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>

    <div id="scrollbox">
        DATA1<br/>
        DATA2<br/>
        DATA3<br/>
        DATA4<br/>
        DATA5<br/>
        DATA6<br/>
        DATA7<br/>
        DATA8<br/>
        DATA9<br/>
        DATA10<br/>
        DATA11<br/>
        DATA12<br/>
        DATA13<br/>
        DATA14<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IE6 support in 2014? Holy moly.

Comment: I know, but this needs to work on windows CE

Comment: Here is a fiddle that solved it using fixed heights: http://jsfiddle.net/9P9fy/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to give the `#scrollbox` a fixed `height` that would make it fit between the two.

In the fiddle, you have a fixed height so the height of the scollbox could be known.

However, with an adjustable height you have problems because CSS can't know the required height without using percentages or flexbox.

I recently made the following demo for another questions which would work for you:

http://codepen.io/helion3/details/FAElH

The trick is to use a wrapper that's positioned at the edges of the header/footer and then allow the inner content to have `height: 100%`, this way the browser will properly auto-adjust the content height.

Comment: that's the problem. I don't have a fixed height.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is not the best solution, but you can use this trick ie. setting the -ve value in bottom like this

```
#footer {
    position : absolute;
    bottom : -60px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LDXhf/7/)**

Comment: This is pushing the footer further down... and there's a gap, etc.

Comment: @helion3 ohh I did that intentionally to make the look same as header. You can change the `-ve`  value as per your need. Now see the fiddle

Comment: I suppose that would work as well, but he'll have to constantly reduce the height of the `#main` div to account for the extension, and if he for some reason ever needs `overflow: hidden`, this will no longer work.

Comment: But I don't know the height of the content. So it is not always -60px.

Comment: @Roeland so you don't know the height of `content` div then you can set the some fixed height to the `scrollbox` div. like this http://jsfiddle.net/LDXhf/8/

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have no choice then to use more fixed heights. These  are the times I don't like CSS because this should be easy to make.